# Is there no standard hash for `std::filesystem::path`?

Tags: c++, hash, c++17

I have a simple program that's intended to store a set of C++17 `std::filesystem::path` objects.  Since there is a [`std::filesystem::hash_value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/hash_value) that's part of the standard, why doesn't this code compile without me having to supply my own `std::hash`?

When I compile and link using gcc 8.1.1 as `g++ -std=c++17 -NO_HASH=1 hashtest.cpp -o hashtest -lstdc++fs` my hash function is included and everything operates perfectly.  However, if I change it to `-NO_HASH=0`, I get a very long list of error messages, the key one of which is this:

```
usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable.h:195:21: error: static assertion failed: hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type
       static_assert(__is_invocable<const _H1&, const _Key&>{},
```

Here's a [live Coliru version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb32ff7b485b1240) if you'd like to play.

**Is there really no defined `std::hash<std::filesystem::path>`?**  What am I missing?

For those who are interested in why I'd want such a thing, it's this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124307/from-new-q-to-compiler-in-30-seconds

### hashtest.cpp

```
#include <optional>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

#if NO_HASH
namespace std {
    template <>
    struct hash<fs::path> {
        std::size_t operator()(const fs::path &path) const {
            return hash_value(path);            }
    };
}
#endif
int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    std::unordered_set< std::optional<fs::path> >  paths = {
            "/usr/bin"s, std::nullopt, "/usr//bin"s, "/var/log"s
    };

    for(const auto& p : paths)
        std::cout << p.value_or("(no path)") << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Notice that your "working" version is technically UB, as you specialize not for **your** type.

Comment: The whole point of the question was exactly to avoid needing to supply one.  I know it's UB.

Comment: You can provide custom hasher and key_equal instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Since there is a `std::filesystem::hash_value` that's part of the standard, why doesn't this code compile without me having to supply my own `std::hash`?

Right, there is a `fs::hash_value()` but there is no specialization of `std::hash<fs::path>`, which is what you would need. That's why it doesn't compile. As to why the library provides the former function but not the latter, I'll quote from [Billy O'Neal](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/4rb294/is_there_any_particular_reason_why/d4zno3h/?st=jix80bdr&sh=ee3007c8) (implementer for MSVC's standard library):

> Looks like a defect.
>
> However, putting paths as keys in a hash table is almost certainly incorrect; you need to test for path equivalence in most such scenarios. That is, `"/foo/bar/../baz"` and `"/foo/baz"` are the same target but are not the same path. Similarly, `"./bar"` and `"./bar"` may be different paths, depending on the value of `current_path` in the first context vs. in the second.

If what you want is canonically unique paths, then simply `std::unordered_set<fs::path>` wouldn't do what you want anyway. So perhaps it failing to compile isn't a bad thing? I don't know enough about filesystem to say one way or the other.

---

Note that you, yourself, providing a specialization of `std::hash` for `fs::path` is not allowed - you can only add specializations to `std` for types you control. Types that will be called "program-defined types." `fs::path` is not a type you control, so you can't specialize `std::hash` for it.

Comment: I've edited the question to add a link that explains the context (just as background).  As for me providing a specialization; you're right that it's not technically allowed; it's one reason I was hoping not to need to!

Comment: They got this from Boost, where `hash_value` is a customization point used by `boost::hash`. Of course, `std::hash` doesn't use this design.

Comment: Tip: You can convert any `fs::path` into a canonical path via `fs::canonical(path)`. So `std::unordered_set<fs::path>` could work (except for the lack of a hash) if you ensure that any path that goes into the `std::unordered_set` is canonical.

Comment: Any pitfalls using fs::canonical as a hasher for the path key? I didn't see this as some kind of workaround for the path keys. And why doesn't it used in the standard library hash<path>?

Answer (score 2):

The resolution was to explicitly write and use my own hash.

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

struct opt_path_hash {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::optional<fs::path>& path) const {
        return path ? hash_value(path.value()) : 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    std::unordered_set< std::optional<fs::path>, opt_path_hash >  paths = {
            "/usr/bin"s, std::nullopt, "/usr//bin"s, "/var/log"s
    };

    for(const auto& p : paths)
        std::cout << p.value_or("(no path)") << '\n';
}
```

This produces the following output, correctly collapsing the two versions of `"/usr/bin"`:

```
"/var/log"
"(no path)"
"/usr/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace hashing {
  namespace adl {
    template<class T, class...Ts>
    auto hash_value( T const& t, Ts&&... )
    -> std::result_of_t< std::hash<T>&&(T const&) >
    {
      return std::hash<T>{}(t);
    }
    template<class T>
    auto hasher_private( T const& t )
    -> decltype( hash_value( t ) )
    { return hash_value(t); }
  }

  struct smart_hasher {
    template<class T>
    auto operator()( T const& t ) const
    ->decltype( adl::hasher_private( t ) )
    {    return adl::hasher_private( t ); }
  };      
};
```

so `hashing::smart_hasher` is a hash object that will look for `hash_value(T const&)` in the namespace of `T`, and if that fails will use `std::hash<T>` if available, and if not will generate a compiler error.

If you want to write additional hashers for `std` types, create a `hash_value` function overload in `hashing::adl`.  For other types, create it in their associated namespace.  For example, if you want to support hashing of `tuple`s:

```
namespace hashing::adl {
  template<class...Ts>
  std::size_t hash_value( std::tuple<Ts...> const& tup ) {
    // get hash values and combine them here
    // use `smart_hasher{}( elem ) to hash each element for
    // recursive smart hashing
  }
}
```

and now anyone using `smart_hasher` automatically picks up the hasher for anything that provides that customization.